# Reload page for urls that don't match any state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an application that is not spa in its entirety (angularjs + ui-router + aspnet5 mvc6). So I have a lot of links that are supposed to trigger a page reload for the server to act on it. I already know that I can use `target="_self"` and such things but this turned painful for my use case, I'd have to keep a watch for all urls in my app.

So what I'm asking is: is there a way to make the page reload for urls that don't match any state? Kind of like `otherwise` but that will simply reload the page for the url that didn't match.

I already looked at the ui-router source, registered rules are not being exposed and you can't check them even if I want. What I had in mind is something like this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (evt, newUrl, oldUrl) {
    // this would be the magic function that will try and match a state.
    var isMatched = match(newUrl);
    if (!isMatched && oldUrl != newUrl) {
        window.location.href = newUrl;
    }
});
```

#### More things I tried:

Using `otherwise`:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(function ($injector, $location) {
    window.location.href = $location.absUrl();
}
```

The problem here is that we have no access to the old url, so this code will cause an endless reload cycle. It would have worked if I can access the old url from inside otherwise.

### **EDIT:**

What I'm trying to do is the following:
The main page of my app `/` doesn't belong to ui-router. The page `/news*` belongs to ui-router. I already configured my server to catch all `/news*` and respond with a page containing `<ui-view />`. This is all good, no problem. I just want one simple thing to happen: **when an anchor with href="/about" is hit, and ui-router fails to match any rule it should simply reload the page for "/about"**.

Comment: You could use something like `$state.go('.', null, { reload: true });`.

Comment: It's not about how to reload, it's really about how to run some code that has access to the old url when we know that there are no matches. See edit for more things I tried.

Comment: It's not really clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  There are two routing engines in play, one mvc and one angular.  if you try to navigate to a url that has no match in angular, it will make the request to the mvc route, unless you have an otherwise.  are you trying to have an otherwise that can sometimes match angular states and sometimes not match angular states?

Comment: Oh, the first behavior you described is what I want. But even without an `otherwise` the page is not reloading. It's simply updating the url and that's it. So, I don't need an `otherwise` but I was trying to get the behavior you described to work.

Comment: are the server routes being called? what is the server returning? can you show some examples of the kinds of urls you are trying?

Comment: are you using `html5Mode`? do you have a `<base>` tag specified in your HTML?  these two things will contribute to how routes are constructed, and to what gets sent to the server or not.

Comment: `html5Mode` is enabled and `requireBase` is false. Is something wrong with this?

Comment: setting `requireBase: false` is probably causing a problem in this case.  As the [angular documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) describes, " Requiring a `<base>` tag is also important for this case, as it allows Angular to differentiate between the part of the url that is the application base and the path that should be handled by the application".

Comment: essentially, without a `<base>`, angular is going to treat all URLs as if they are part of your app, meaning that if your app is running under `/news/` and you navigate to `/about`, angular is going to treat it like you put in `/news/about`.  You probably need `<base='/news'>` specified, but you'll have to be careful with your JS and stylesheet references in this case.

Comment: Right, I'll play a little bit with `<base>` then to see if it makes a difference, thanks.

Comment: `<base>` didn't solve my problem unfortunately. After more reading, the problem would have been easy to solve if the `otherwise` function exposed the old url from the `$locationChangeSuccess`. I opened an issue but it was almost instantly closed. Too bad.

Comment: what do you mean almost instantly closed? can you link the issue you opened? did the ui-router team say why they were closing the issue, or offer a potential solution?  I've  been trying to set something up to re-create the issue you are describing, but it's rather hard to just make guesses at what is going wrong with your code;  You haven't posted any code showing exactly how your links are constructed in the HTML.

Comment: In other words, it's hard to tell if this is a failure on the part of ui-router or if this is a failure in MVC to return the correct page.  It's still not obvious if your server is ever receiving the page request or not, and if it is, what it is responding with.